# Unable to target anchor with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to be able to hide a second child if one exists.

https://jsfiddle.net/b7vg2qsp/

```css
#mob-links li:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mob-links">
  <li><a href="../../inventory.php">Inventory</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../../ah/">Market</a>  <a href="../../ah/">second link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I googled and google and I couldn't find something that says anchors are not selectable by nth-child.

Comment: Do you want to hide the second anchor tag inside the list element or the second list element? Please specify your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What second child? What denotes a second child in your mind?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide the second anchor "Second Link".  I need to hide the second child if one exists as stated in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select anchor tags as well:

```
#mob-links li > a:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7vg2qsp/1/)

Comment: I edited, your answer, but thank you that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is separate the pseudo-selector from the type selector:

```css
#mob-links li :nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mob-links">
  <li><a href="../../inventory.php">Inventory</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../../ah/">Market</a>  <a href="../../ah/">second link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When you concatenate the selectors, they're applied at the same level. Using a whitespace separator selects descendants. You could be more specific with the `>` direct descendant (child...) selector.

Comment: Oh.  I did not realize all I had done wrong was a lack of a space for type separation.  Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

if it is about links within `li`, then the selector : `~` would do . (only the first link would be shown here, no matter if text stand in between ).

```css
#mob-links li a ~ a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mob-links">
  <li><a href="../../inventory.php">Inventory</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../../ah/">Market</a>  <a href="../../ah/">second link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```